# How do I pull Git History in for files that have been moved to a different repository

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have moved files from multiple packages into a new repository, and have managed to keep the history so far by using the command below.

```
    git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached -qr --ignore- unmatch -- . && git reset -q $GIT_COMMIT -- path/to/folder path/to/other/folder' --prune-empty HEAD
```

If these files are further edited in the original repository, how can I pull in these changes to my new repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the second remote to your original repository and then fetch from it to you "old location".

Now once you have all the data from the 2 repos use cherry-pick to grab the desired commits,

```
# add second remote
git remote add origin_2 <url>

# fetch all the remotes
git fetch --all

# checkout the desired branch
git checkout <branch>

# git cherry-pick <commit id from the new repo >
```

---

#### `git cherry-pick <SHA-1>`

> Apply the change introduced by the commit(s) at the tip of the master branch and create a new commit(s) with this change.

The syntax of the `...` is a commit range. grab all commits from start (exclude) to the last one. If you want a single commit use a single SHA-1

[image]

---

Read out the full [***`git cherry-pick`*** documentation for all the options you can use](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)

Comment: This was my solution also. I ended up doing the following:
1. finding the shared commit between the two repos (obviously different sha's)
2. piping 'git rev-list <HEAD..<shared-commit-sha>' to a file, and 
3. writing a bash script to cherry-pick those commits that modified my files, and only add new files containing a certain name relevant to classes in the repo, otherwise the commit is discarded and move the same actions repeated on the next one.